# Unable to delete google app engine flex environment instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried to delete two instance via the console

[image]

However I got this message at the bottom in the gcp console.

[image]

and here is the text of the notification

[image]

How can I find why they cannot be deleted?

My goal is to retire them entirely. I am happy to learn how to complete shutdown and remove these instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to stop the "version" running them. Go to versions and stop the one related to this instances. Otherwise they will be recreated anyway later on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to remove the service entirely? The 'Delete' button does not allow to delete the last version of the service.

Comment: You can delete any service except the default one. Unless you delete your whole project. Read more on it [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/delete-tutorial-resources#deleting_app_versions).